# Reading squarewave signal from sensor

Tags: python, frequency, sensors, pwm

I am using a radar sensor which provides square wave according to the speed of object it is sensing. I want to calculate speed of object with changing frequency of square wave signal. Following code gives frequency but my problem is that code keeps on printing last value even when there is no input signal at gpio pin. How to make it to zero or stop printing last value.

```
import time
import pigpio
import read_PWM
PWM_GPIO = 21
SAMPLE_TIME = 1.0
pi = pigpio.pi()
p = read_PWM.reader(pi, PWM_GPIO)
while True:
      time.sleep(SAMPLE_TIME)  
      f = p.frequency()
      pw = p.pulse_width()
      dc = p.duty_cycle()
      print(f)
```

Comment: Then you need to differentiate somehow when it is a sensor data, and when not, e.g. by sending the `DATA_READY` signal from the sensor if it supports it and handing its reception in your code. Or differentiate by value domain, e.g. making assumption that sensor always senses different values, and if the value is the same as in previous iteration it is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a NOT gate that turns on when there is no signal to the GPIO pin.

then you could change your code to be like:

```
import time
import pigpio
import read_PWM
PWM_GPIO = 21
SAMPLE_TIME = 1.0
pi = pigpio.pi()
p = read_PWM.reader(pi, PWM_GPIO)
p2 = read_(whateverthisimplementations HIGH, LOW basic read is)
while True:
      time.sleep(SAMPLE_TIME)  
      f = p.frequency()
      pw = p.pulse_width()
      dc = p.duty_cycle()
      if p2 != HIGH:
           print(f)
```